# PHP: substr runway loop

Tags: php, loops

Here's a part of my code

```
    $hold = $this->content;
    $hold_table = array();
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($hold); $i++){
        $t = substr($hold, $i, 10);
        $count = substr_count($hold, $t);
        if($count > 1){
            $hold = str_replace($t, '', $hold); //Just iterating for now to get counts
            $hold_table[bin2hex($t)] = $count;
        }
    }
```

`$this->content` is a file that is read in.

If the "10" in this line: `$t = substr($hold, $i, 10);` is 10 or lower, it works fine and spits out the result fine.

If I change the 10 to say, "15".  The script just hangs in a loop.

I don't think there is any array key size limitations that I'm running in to and the "FOR" loop should end if `$i > strlen($hold)`

Any ideas why changing from 10 to 15 causes chaos?

Comment: I can actually push to 14 with no problems

Comment: You are trying to do something **really** strange. You loop through the string until it's end and on each iteration you try to get substring starting from current char with length 10. So, I really don't understand why it words. What do you expect `substr` return when `$i` is `strlen($hold)-1`? Of course it's smart enough not to crash, but still, it's rather strange approach

Comment: Correct.  But if the string matches more than once, I'm pulling it out, thus my reason for leaving the counter where it's out.  I'm wanting to eliminate as much of the string as possible with recurrence.  Are you suggesting I catch that error by checking the strlen before the next loop?  It seems unnecessary when the for loop  should catch that.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal for that piece of code? Maybe it can be achiveved with [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) with `g` modifier?

Comment: It's a basic compression...byte pairing.  I just achieve better compression results with a higher number on the first pass.  Maybe I'll stick with traditional byte pairing though.

Comment: Maybe [Compression and Archive Extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) would be helpful?

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2605/discussion-between-j0hn-and-senica-gonzalez)

Answer (score 1):

You are changing $hold along the way by your str_replace statement (shortening it basically). I think that's producing some unexpected results.